# jQuery video frame preview on image hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a preview of a video when the user hovers an image (like youtube).

The images are taken from FFmpeg that get a frame every 100 and saved in the same directory of the first loaded image named eg: `20-1.jpg`. 
When the user puts the mouse on the first image, it should cycle through the other images named eg: `20-2.jpg`, `20-3.jpg`, `20,4.jpg` etc.

**HTML**

Getting the ID of the item from `Twig` `{{result.id}}`

```
<div class="card result-card" onmouseover="updateThumb({{ result.id }})">
    <a href="{{ url('vedi_oggetto',  {'category': catName,'item': result.id,'title': slug}) }}">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" id="imgPreview-{{ result.id }}" src="/uploads/photos/{{ result.id }}-1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    </a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function updateThumb(id) {
   var timer,
       count = 1,
       cycle = function(el){
           var s = el.attr('src'),
           root = s.substring( 0, s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1 );
           count = (count+1)%5;
           el.attr('src', root + '2-' + ((count===0) ? '5' : count) + '.jpg');
       };
       $('#imgPreview-' + id).hover(function(){
           var $this = $(this);
           cycle($this);
           timer = setInterval(function(){ cycle($this); }, 800);
       }, function(){
           clearInterval(timer);
       });
   }
```

The problem is that when I hover on the first image it works and cycle as expected. But, when I hover on the second image or others, it shows the first image cycle on all, so it works only for one image.

Comment: On each `mouseover` you assign another `$('#imgPreview-' + id).hover(function(){..})` event, it is wrong mate :)

Comment: Also, better use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, cause... you could lose the image hover... and try to preload the images before replacing the image `src` attribute. Good luck

Comment: Guys, thanks for your ideas, It's possible to post an example in a reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have two images with IDs 20 and 30, than you can go this way:

```js
var cycle = function(el) {
    var s = el.attr('src');
    var root = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
    var count = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('-') + 1).replace('.jpg', '');
    count = (count*1+1)%5;
    console.log(count);
    console.log('-------');
    el.attr('src', root + ((count === 0) ? '5' : count) + '.jpg');
};
$('body').on('mouseenter', '[id^=imgPreview-]', function(e) {
    var thisImage = $(this);
    var timer;
    cycle(thisImage);
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        cycle(thisImage);
    }, 800);
    thisImage.on('mouseleave', function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="imgPreview-20" src="/uploads/photos/20-1.jpg" />
<img id="imgPreview-30" src="/uploads/photos/30-1.jpg" />
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjzkxj41/).

Besides all other problems I mentioned in comments, you have always used ID 2 to generate the image source in this line:

```
el.attr('src', root + '2-' + ((count===0) ? '5' : count) + '.jpg');
```

Comment: Thank you man, you make my day! Now I've understood why I only got the 2-*.jpg file, damn!